# iOS - change orientation of an UIImage based on coordinates

Tags: ios, uiview, uiimage

I got an UIImage inside a UIView. I want to be able to set the orientation of the image based on the X,Y coordinates. I've been looking at UIImageOrientation property but it only allows me to use a select number of different orientations (up, down, right, left, etc..) which is not precise enough.

Is there any good way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to rotate an UIImageView by an arbitrary angle?

If so you can do this:

```
imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angleInRadians);
```

Comment: I see, can you do this on UIView's as well? Also, how do you calculate the angle based on the X,Y coordinates? Thanks

Comment: Yes, transform is a property of UIView! About your angle, well that entirely depends on the behaviour you want.